# FlexSlider not showing up at all and captions are not showing correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, slideshow

Can someone help me figure out why my flexslider isn't appearing on my page? I have no idea what the issue is.

http://stweb.ccv.edu/CIS-1151-VO02-V13FA/kak10200/final_project/index.html

It is just a white line right now. Here's the code I have implemented based on a tutorial:

```
<!-- Flexslider CSS and JS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flex/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.your_domain.com/flex/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<!-- Load the flexslider -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",  // slide or fade
      controlsContainer: ".flex-container" // the container that holds the flexslider
    });
  });
</script>

            <div class="flexslider">
              <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                  <img src="flex/images/slide1.png" /><p class="flex-caption">Captions and brownies. A winning combination.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="flex/images/slide2.png" /><p class="flex-caption">Captions and brownies. A winning combination.</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

UPDATE:
So I can now see the slider, but it's very messed up for some reason. Any ideas? Also, does anyone know how to make sure my drop down menu is over the slider rather than beneath it?

Comment: I think you want to give `.flexslider .slides li` `position: relative` so that your absolute positioned `<p>` elements are positioned properly. For the drop down menu you can probably fix that using a z-index rule in your css. Also slide2.png is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove `http://www.your_domain.com` in the script tag.

Edit the flexslider css like this:

```
.flexslider .slides img {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    display: block;
}
```

NOTE: You could also remove this whole block, if this are ment to be custom styles.

Add those to your **own** style.css:

```
.flexslider .slides li {
    position: relative;
}

.flexslider .flex-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Also please fix your source images use `ctrl-shift-j` in chrome to see which are missing.

Change the **flexslider** styleheet by this one: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/css/flexslider.css

Comment: Okay the link above should be updated. I changed some things and it looks better now, but the slider navigation isn't working right... the image is messed up for the directions. I also can't figure out some of the source image issues.

Comment: Please replace your whole stylesheet except the styles I gave you, by this one: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/css/flexslider.css this will fix your problems.

Comment: You are my hero. It looks great now, though it's a bit hard to see the direction arrows with the pictures.

Comment: Any idea why the text on the captions looks bold on chrome and normal on safari?

Comment: Forget about the opacity thing, you should change the images if you want them more clear, maybe try your luck with GIMP

Comment: Upvote it as well, commendable effort in answering this question. @OP maybe you should edit the question, because it is more than just the script tag that was wrong. This way future visitors will have help as well.

Comment: About safari and chrome: It is because of the different user agent stylesheets I guess. You can use `font-weight: normal;` or `font-weight: bold;` to force the way you want. in the `.flex-caption` css

Comment: Okay. Thanks again for all of your help. Now I need to solve the strange issues with it when being viewed on iPhone...

Comment: use `media screen` queries

Answer (score 0):

Remove `http://www.your_domain.com/` in the `script` `src` attribute.

Comment: Wowwww, haha. Thank you! I'm such an idiot, this is my first website so I apologize for the stupidity.

Comment: Now it is showing up but it's incredibly messed up still... ughhh.

Comment: Did you modified the css yourself?

Comment: @NickN. I have this in the code for the slides to make a caption:

<p class="flex-caption">We sell <a href="steel.html">steel</a> and <a href="custom.html">custom</a> residential doors. <a href="residential.html">Click here</a> for a listing of our residential garage door and electric opener distributors!</p>

Style:
.flex-caption {
   width: 96%;
   padding: 2%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   font-size: 99%;
   line-height: 10px;
   margin:0;
   height: auto;
}